# Running .NET Program As A Service

Tags: vb.net, service

I have a program that is written in VB.NET.  It is currently interactive in that the user will click on some buttons on the form and click "GO" and it will do it's stuff.

I would like to set this up via a service on a Windows PC and instead of having user inputs via clicks have all the information in a config file.

It is my understanding that I can set this up as a service with some "parameters" on the call line, etc. and get other information from the config file.

Can someone advise me on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware the software must have a [ServiceInstaller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller.aspx) class to install the service and a Service class that inherits from [ServiceBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.aspx).

This would enable Windows to install, stop and start the service via the command line and  services menu respectively.

[Here's](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3990/Simple-Windows-Service-Sample) a simple example

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make some small changes to convert your program to a Windows Service.

First, you will want to remove the user interface entirely - services shouldn't have a user interface.

You'd then build in the service plumbing required.  Visual Studio includes a design experience specifically for creating Windows Services.  For details on this, see the [Creating a Windows Service Application in the Component Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).